# Sintaxis de top, orden by y distinct al mismo tiempo

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente situación, me pidieron hacer un proyecto con una base de datos SQL ya creada, el problema es que me pidieron que seleccionará los 35 primeros registros y los ordenara de forma descendente, hasta ahí lo entiendo pero también me dijeron que no se deben de repetir los datos y ya no sé qué sintaxis utilizar.
Esta es la consulta que utilice:

```
SELECT TOP 35 CustomerID FROM Orders ORDER BY CustomerID DESC
```

Lo que me faltaría es utilizar el `DISTINCT` en la misma consulta para que los datos de ´CustomerID´ no se repitan

Comment: Debes dar más detalles, poner la estructura de tu tabla y poner el codigo que has intentado, edita tu pregunta y agrega todo eso

Comment: ¿`distinct`, para que no se repitan?

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Comment: Pon los campos de tu tabla, y di cuales de ellos quieres poner en el select

Comment: Se recomienda optar por mostrar imagenes relacionas al problema o compartir la parte del codigo para obtener ayuda, te recomiento reformular la pregunta y hacer el recorrido https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Hola dayana, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar datos repetidos puedes usar la **cláusula group by**, la cual hace un resumen de tus datos, eliminando los registros duplicados:

```
select top 35 CustomerId
from orders 
group by CustomerId
order by CustomerId desc
```

El **group by** se usa para muchas cosas, en este caso solo hace un resumen de los datos por la **columna CustomerId**. Puedes investigar más en Internet.

Comment: Es mejor usar DISTINCT para eliminar repetidos y GROUP BY para agrupar en funciones de agregado.

Comment: @LuisCazares, en este caso da lo mismo